# Equivalent of each loop from gsp to controller method

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Assuming this is in a gsp currently:

```
<g:each in="${prospectProjectStatuses}" var="statusObj">
    <%-- Number active and inactive projects --%>
    <g:if test="${statusObj?.project?.active == true}">
        <g:set var="numActiveProjects" value="${numActiveProjects + 1}"/>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        <g:set var="numInactiveProjects" value="${numInactiveProjects + 1}"/>
    </g:else>

    <%-- Number of hidden rows to show --%>
    <g:if test="${!statusObj?.project?.id.intValue() && !canEdit && statusObj?.status?.id}">
        <g:set var="numProjectsToShow" value="${numProjectsToShow + 1}"/>
    </g:if>

    <g:if test="${statusObj?.project?.active && statusObj?.status?.id}">
        <g:set var="numStatusSet" value="${numStatusSet + 1}"/>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```

What's the equivalent of an each loop within the controller method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call each() on your collection. So the equivalent for your example gsp would look like:

```
prospectProjectStatuses.each { statusObj -> 
    if (statusObj?.project?.active) {
        numActiveProjects += 1
    } else {
        numInactiveProjects += 1
    }
    if (statusObj?.project?.id.intValue() && !canEdit && statusObj?.status?.id) {
        numProjectsToShow += 1
    }
    if {statusObj?.project?.active && statusObj?.status?.id) {
        numStatusSet += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: That was extremely fast. Thanks... this will definitely help in the future (only knew how to do it w/in the gsp before) :)

Comment: @bob_cobb: also check out the collect and inject methods (equivalents of map and reduce).